# MySQL - count how many rows in next 5 seconds for each record

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table `tb`:

```
ApplyID, ApplyDate,  
=================================  
John,    2008-01-23 12:00:01    
Joe,     2008-01-23 12:00:02  
Mary,    2008-01-23 12:00:02  
Snoopy,  2008-01-23 12:00:06  
Snoopy,  2008-01-23 12:00:07  
Snoopy,  2008-01-23 12:00:11  
John,    2008-01-23 12:00:21
```

I want to count how many rows in next 5 seconds for each row.
Output like:

```
ApplyID, ApplyDate, Sessions
=================================  
John,    2008-01-23 12:00:01, 3   
Joe,     2008-01-23 12:00:02, 4  
Mary,    2008-01-23 12:00:02, 4  
Snoopy,  2008-01-23 12:00:06, 3  
Snoopy,  2008-01-23 12:00:07, 2  
Snoopy,  2008-01-23 12:00:11, 1  
John,    2008-01-23 12:00:21, 1
```

The query I use:

```
SELECT p1.ApplyID, 
    p1.ApplyDate,
   (
     SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM tb p2
     WHERE p2.ApplyDate >= p1.ApplyDate
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p2.ApplyDate)- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p1.ApplyDate) <= 5
   ) AS sessions
FROM tb p1
ORDER BY ApplyDate
```

It works but will take a long time to show result. Any better way to increase query performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes a `join` outperforms a subquery.  You could try:

```
select  p1.ApplyID
,       p1.ApplyDate,
,       count(*)
from    tb p1
join    tb p2
on      p2.ApplyDate between p1.ApplyDate and p1.ApplyDate + interval 5 second
group by
        p1.ApplyID
,       p1.ApplyDate
order by
        p1.ApplyDate
```

Creating an index on `ApplyDate` might help:

```
create index IX_TB_ApplyDate on tb (ApplyDate, ApplyID)
```

Two notes.  Because you only select `ApplyID` and `ApplyDate`, this index is even covering for your query.  And make sure your query doesn't use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, which may prevent MySQL from using the index.

Comment: I like how this answer doesn't require a function-based index for optimization, but `p2.cnt` in the `SELECT` list should be `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(p2.ApplyDate)` or something similar instead. It could also use a `GROUP BY`, though I know MySQL is pretty permissive about this :)

Comment: Still spent a long time for this query. 20k rows took over 5 mins. But   thanks that this answer let me know that UNIX_TIMESTAMP will prevent MySQL to use the index.  Maybe I will try to write a php or perl script to get the result. ( these records were old fixed data and won't be modified. )

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p1.ApplyID, p1.ApplyDate, COUNT(*) as SESSIONS
FROM tb p1, tb p2
WHERE p2.ApplyDate >= p1.ApplyDate
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p2.ApplyDate)- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p1.ApplyDate) <= 5
ORDER BY p1.ApplyDate
```